# Web App Project with 2 module(Dynamic Web project)- How to link from default to another module?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, module

i'm doing a sample for to learn Google Appe Engine (GAE). 
In my example HELLO WORLD i have created ENTERPRISE APPLICATION PROJECT with 2 Dynamic Web project inside:

```
-Giuseppeit_default->module:default
-Giuseppeit_task->module:task
```

Now when i run locally my project i view only default Module. I have changed Giuseppeit_default's index.html like:

```
 <body>
    <h1>Ciao Giuseppe!</h1>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Available Servlets:</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="giuseppeit_default">GiuseppeIT_default</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="giuseppeit_task">GiuseppeIT_task</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

I want a new link to second Module Giuseppeit_task. 
I have created dispatch.xml in: Giuseppeit_default\WebContent\dispatch.xml like:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<dispatch-entries>
    <dispatch>
        <url>localhost/</url>
        <module>default</module>
    </dispatch>
    <dispatch>
        <url>*/giuseppeit_task/*</url>
        <module>task</module>
    </dispatch>
</dispatch-entries>
```

Now when i run my project i view 2 link:

GiuseppeIT_default
GiuseppeIT_task

But when i click on GiuseppeIT_task i view ERROR 404. Why? where is the problem?

Thanks for help me
Regards
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0):

Your first dispatch rule catches **all** requests for the development server (they're all served by localhost) and sends them to the default module, which likely doesn't have a handler for the task url you're requesting. I'd drop that 1st rule - not needed anyways since requests not matching any dispatch rule are sent to the default module.